# Почему при входе всегда получаю Invalid credentials?

Tags: symfony2, symfony, symfony3

После регистрации пытаюсь войти, но всегда получаю `Invalid credentials`.

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    OwrBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: OwrBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: admin
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        anonymous: true
        security: true

access_control:
    - { path: /admin/.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php
namespace OwrBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->attributes->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $request->getSession()->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render('OwrBundle:Page:login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $request->getSession()->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error' => $error
        ));
    }
}
```

RegisterController.php

```
<?php
namespace OwrBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\{ Request, Response };
use OwrBundle\Entity\{ Role, User };
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\{ Filesystem, Exception\IOExceptionInterface };

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);

        //...

        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);

        //...

        return new Response('Ok');
    }
}
```

dev.log

```
[2017-08-14 18:05:57] request.INFO: Matched route "_security_check". {"route":"_security_check","route_parameters":{"_route":"_security_check"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_check","method":"POST"} []
[2017-08-14 18:05:57] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.user_id AS user_id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.fname AS fname_4, t0.sname AS sname_5, t0.gender AS gender_6, t0.birth AS birth_7, t0.phone AS phone_8, t0.about AS about_9, t0.city_id AS city_id_10, t0.address AS address_11, t0.passport AS passport_12, t0.created AS created_13, t0.avatar AS avatar_14, t0.partner AS partner_15, t0.balance AS balance_16, t0.verified AS verified_17, t0.passport_verified AS passport_verified_18, t0.email_verified AS email_verified_19, t0.phone_verified AS phone_verified_20, t0.rating_owner AS rating_owner_21, t0.rating_passport AS rating_passport_22, t0.rating_partner AS rating_partner_23, t0.is_active AS is_active_24 FROM "user" t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1 ["viliam@gmail.com"] []
[2017-08-14 18:05:59] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /Users/viktor/symfony/owr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:90, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): The presented password is invalid. at /Users/viktor/symfony/owr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:67)"} []
[2017-08-14 18:05:59] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"/login"} []
[2017-08-14 18:06:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_security_login". {"route":"_security_login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"OwrBundle\\Controller\\LoginController::showAction","_route":"_security_login"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login","method":"GET"} []
[2017-08-14 18:06:00] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-08-14 18:06:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_assetic_1956b98_0". {"route":"_assetic_1956b98_0","route_parameters":{"_controller":"assetic.controller:render","name":"1956b98","pos":0,"_format":"css","_route":"_assetic_1956b98_0"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/style_bootstrap.min_1.css","method":"GET"} []
[2017-08-14 18:06:00] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-08-14 18:06:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_assetic_1956b98_1". {"route":"_assetic_1956b98_1","route_parameters":{"_controller":"assetic.controller:render","name":"1956b98","pos":1,"_format":"css","_route":"_assetic_1956b98_1"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/style_style_2.css","method":"GET"} []
[2017-08-14 18:06:00] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-08-14 18:06:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_assetic_a6a2f7e_0". {"route":"_assetic_a6a2f7e_0","route_parameters":{"_controller":"assetic.controller:render","name":"a6a2f7e","pos":0,"_format":"js","_route":"_assetic_a6a2f7e_0"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/app_jquery_1.js","method":"GET"} []
[2017-08-14 18:06:01] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-08-14 18:06:01] request.INFO: Matched route "_assetic_a6a2f7e_1". {"route":"_assetic_a6a2f7e_1","route_parameters":{"_controller":"assetic.controller:render","name":"a6a2f7e","pos":1,"_format":"js","_route":"_assetic_a6a2f7e_1"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/app_ion.rangeSlider.min_2.js","method":"GET"} []
[2017-08-14 18:06:01] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-08-14 18:06:01] request.INFO: Matched route "_assetic_a6a2f7e_2". {"route":"_assetic_a6a2f7e_2","route_parameters":{"_controller":"assetic.controller:render","name":"a6a2f7e","pos":2,"_format":"js","_route":"_assetic_a6a2f7e_2"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/app_jquery.datetimepicker.min_3.js","method":"GET"} []
[2017-08-14 18:06:01] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-08-14 18:06:01] request.INFO: Matched route "_assetic_a6a2f7e_3". {"route":"_assetic_a6a2f7e_3","route_parameters":{"_controller":"assetic.controller:render","name":"a6a2f7e","pos":3,"_format":"js","_route":"_assetic_a6a2f7e_3"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/app_app_4.js","method":"GET"} []
[2017-08-14 18:06:01] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-08-14 18:06:02] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"4d54bc","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/_wdt/4d54bc","method":"GET"} []
```

Соль не использую ибо алгоритм кодирования bcrypt.

Как это починить? Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040133/symfony-fosuserbundle-login-invalid-credentials пробовали использовать setPlainPassword ?